# Google Dataflow: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot setCoder(null)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to build a custom sink for unzipping files.

Having this simple code:

```
public static class ZipIO{    
  public static class Sink extends com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.Sink<String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7414200726778377175L;
    private final String unzipTarget;

      public Sink withDestinationPath(String s){
         if(s!=""){
             return new Sink(s);
         }
         else {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("must assign destination path");
         }

      }

      protected Sink(String path){
          this.unzipTarget = path;
      }

      @Override
      public void validate(PipelineOptions po){
          if(unzipTarget==null){
              throw new RuntimeException();
          }
      } 

      @Override
      public ZipFileWriteOperation createWriteOperation(PipelineOptions po){
          return new ZipFileWriteOperation(this);
      }

  }

  private static class ZipFileWriteOperation extends WriteOperation<String, UnzipResult>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7976541367499831605L;
    private final ZipIO.Sink sink;

      public ZipFileWriteOperation(ZipIO.Sink sink){
          this.sink = sink;
      }



      @Override
      public void initialize(PipelineOptions po) throws Exception{

      }

      @Override
      public void finalize(Iterable<UnzipResult> writerResults, PipelineOptions po) throws Exception {
         long totalFiles = 0;
         for(UnzipResult r:writerResults){
             totalFiles +=r.filesUnziped;
         }
         LOG.info("Unzipped {} Files",totalFiles);
      }  

      @Override
      public ZipIO.Sink getSink(){
          return sink;
      }

      @Override
      public ZipWriter createWriter(PipelineOptions po) throws Exception{
          return new ZipWriter(this);
      }

  }

  private static class ZipWriter extends Writer<String, UnzipResult>{
      private final ZipFileWriteOperation writeOp;
      public long totalUnzipped = 0;

      ZipWriter(ZipFileWriteOperation writeOp){
          this.writeOp = writeOp;
      }

      @Override
      public void open(String uID) throws Exception{
      }

      @Override
      public void write(String p){
            System.out.println(p);
      }

      @Override
      public UnzipResult close() throws Exception{
          return new UnzipResult(this.totalUnzipped);
      }

      @Override
      public ZipFileWriteOperation getWriteOperation(){
          return writeOp;
      }


  }

  private static class UnzipResult implements Serializable{  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8504626439217544799L;
    public long filesUnziped=0;      
      public UnzipResult(long filesUnziped){
          this.filesUnziped=filesUnziped;
      }
  }
}
```

}

The processing fails with error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot setCoder(null)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TypedPValue.setCoder(TypedPValue.java:67)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection.setCoder(PCollection.java:150)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.Write$Bound.createWrite(Write.java:380)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.Write$Bound.apply(Write.java:112)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner$BatchWrite.apply(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:2118)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner$BatchWrite.apply(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:2099)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.PipelineRunner.apply(PipelineRunner.java:75)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.apply(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:465)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.apply(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:169)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:368)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:275)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner.apply(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:463)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.apply(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:169)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:368)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:291)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:174)
>       at com.mcd.de.tlogdataflow.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:93)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks & BR
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This crash is caused by a bug in the Dataflow Java SDK ([specifically, this line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/Sink.java#L213)) which was also present in the Apache Beam (incubating) Java SDK.

The method `Sink.WriterOperation#getWriterResultCoder()` must always be overridden, but we failed to mark it `abstract`. It is fixed in Beam, but unchanged in the Dataflow SDK. You should override this method and return an appropriate coder.

You have some options to come up with the coder:

1. Write your own small coder class, wrapping one of `VarLongCoder` or `BigEndianLongCoder`
2. Just use a `long` instead of the `UnzipResult` structure so you can use those as-is.
3. Less advisable due to the excess size, you could use `SerializableCoder.of(UnzipResult.class)`

Comment: Hi Kenn, thanks for your help. I changed it to a Long structure with the close() operation returning a long. Still, I get the same cannot setCoder(null) Exception.

Comment: Hi Kenn, did you find a solution for this? Thanks & BR Philipp

Comment: Did you override `getWriterResultCoder()`? That is what you will need to do.

Comment: Hi Kenn, that was exactly what I needed to do. Thank you very much. They should propably put it in the documentation of custom sinks somewhere...